# What do you call non-keyframe animations in CSS and do they trigger events?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

CSS offers two ways to animate elements:

**a. Via [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)**, e.g.:

```
<button>Click me</button>

button {
  transition: 500ms;
}
button.moved {
  transform: translateX(50vw);
}

$('button').click( function( event ) {
  $(this).toggleClass('moved');
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/wVzwdR)

**b. Via [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)**, e.g.:

```
<button>Click me</button>

button.moved {
  animation: move 500ms both;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(50vw);
  }
}

$('button').click( function( event ) {
  $(this).toggleClass('moved');
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/wVzwPO)

## Terminology

The second type are called keyframe animations, but what is the first one called?

Trying to clarify the terminology to make searching on this easier in the future.

## Events

The end of a keyframe animation can be detected using the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event. Is there any way to detect the end of an animation in the first case? i.e.: in the example, when the button arrives in the middle of the screen.

For now I'm using a CSS custom property, which is then read by JavaScript and used to set a timer, so as to use the same timing in each, but this feels unclean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+pause+transition

Comment: like animationend there is also transitionend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

Comment: for the official definition: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/ / https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/